# How to apply i18n on selection on the view page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rails-i18n

I want to apply i18n on `Customer::ROLES` array,

The value in Customer::ROLES is `general, vip, platinum` array

But I got errors when I wrapped it in this way `t(Customer::ROLES , scope:  'CUSTOMER')`

```
= f.input :role,label: t("role"),as: :select, |
 :collection => Customer::ROLES, |
 :selected => 1
```

here's the yml file

```
CUSTOMER:
    platinum: "白金"
    vip: "vip"
```

here's the error message

```
 NoMethodError in Customers#edit

undefined method `to_a' for #<ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer:0x007fe0e76b6e88>
```

Answer (score 0):

like this way u can set the I18 value

```
<%= I18n.t 'CUSTOMER.platinum'%>
```

Comment: you didn't understand the question, i want to apply translate on an array object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether Rails in general supports this, but simple_form certainly does:

```
f.input :role, collection: [...]
```

will try to translate the elements in the given collection array. It will look in the .yaml file for something like

```
simple_form:
  options:
    customer:
      role:
        platinum: ...
        vip: ...
```

(see https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)